# Linux, C-shell, save Awk string output to a variable and preserve special characters in string

Tags: linux, variables, awk, special-characters, csh

I have a csv file with string data.

The string, `1000/06{a-09}90.log`, is in row 236 and column 6.

I tried to save the string in a variable using the command below. This command doesn't preserve the curly brackets.

```
set var = `awk -F ',' 'NR==236{print $6}' File.csv`
```

`echo $var` results in: `1000/06a-0990.log` <- missing {}

How can I save the string and preserve the special characters?

Comment: @tripleee I don't think this is a duplicate of your link. This is about csh, not bash. If OP runs in bash, there will be no problem.

Comment: Is not using csh but using bash or similar instead an option?

Comment: In this detail, even the wicked `csh` behaves the same as modern shells.

Comment: Here's that link again: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: @tripleee Putting quotes around `$var` will not make `{}` appear because they are not in `$var`.

Answer (score 1):

Curly braces are for brace expansion, that's why they are removed.

Use double quotes to prevent brace expansion:

```
set dollar6='$6'
set var = "`awk -F ',' 'NR==1{print $dollar6; exit}' File.csv`"
echo "$var"
```

Comment: When I use the double quotes as you suggested, the entire row is returned and the commas no longer behave as a delimiter.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and it returns the entire row. The {} are preserved, but I'm not getting the targeted string in column 6.

Comment: Indeed there was a problem, I suggested a workaround.

Comment: Don't let shell variables expand to become part of the body of an awk script, see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script). Adjust the syntax to csh if necessary but the advice is the same.

Comment: @EdMorton It's like `avoid eval` rule, somtimes you have to break it.

Comment: Yes, you have to break it to implement using awk language constructs that are defined in a shell variable, e.g.: `op='+'; echo '3 4' | awk '{print $1 '"$op"' $2}'`, but that's very rare and neither necessary nor useful in this case.

Comment: My original script was this `set var = "`awk -F ',' 'NR==1{print $6; exit}' File.csv`"`. But csh does expansion so the actual awk command is this : `awk -F ',' 'NR==1{print; exit}' File.csv`. Do you have a better solution to keep `$6` ?

Comment: @EdMorton You can take a look at the original script from the history.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't written a csh script for 38 years, I don't recall anything about the syntax but surely you can do `awk -F ',' -v col="$var" 'NR==1{print $col; exit}' File.csv` or similar.

Comment: @EdMorton We need a literal `$6` after `print`. your `-v col="$var"` won't work.

Comment: Are you saying that when running CSH I can't call an awk script like `awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{col=4} NR==1{print $col; exit}' File.csv` because somehow CSH won't let awk use an awk variable to hold a field number, or that it's impossible to set an awk variable from the value of a shell variable or something else? Like I say, I don't remember anything about CSH syntax so I'll believe whatever you tell me.

Comment: @EdMorton You can call in csh awk script like `awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{col=4} NR==1{print $col; exit}' File.csv`. But when you try to do `set var = "awk ... command"` csh will do a first level variable expansion which would eliminate $col.